# cucumber -skip before hook in certain examples

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, cucumber

In my case some features are launching the UI before every step because of before feature hook which has a logic to launch URL in browser but in some features I just need to perform some post request and does not want to launch any URL .So is there any way to skip executing this before hook.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: After searching i found one way to skip the file that containing this hook is glob pattern...can anyone suggest how to use these patterns in config file to exclude some steps file in cucumberOpts option?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Before()
public void priorToScenarioExecution(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.getId().equals("Some feature;scenario name") {  
        //Skip whatever you want to skip
    } else {
       // Do whatever you normally do
    }
```

The scenario id is the concatenation of

```
"<feature name>;<scenario name>",
```

or in case of scenario outlines, the concatenation of

```
 "<feature name>;<scenario outline name>;<examples group name>;<table row number>".
```

Print scenario.getId() out in your before hook so that you know the exact string to look for.

You can also use [tags in before hooks](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/writing-support-code/tagged-hooks).

Comment: @n.bhv Did you get a chance to try this?